# depthimage_to_laserscan Asus xtion, Use centre pixels?

Tags: ros, camera-depth-points, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to set my depth camera to use the centre pixels for the laser scan as the scan currently uses the bottom pixels so I have to tilt the camera which is causing inaccurate depth  measurements.

Could I create a camera_info.yaml file and indicate the region of interest (roi)? If so How is there any example of this being done?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218592/depthimage_to_laserscan-asus-xtion,-use-centre-pixels?/) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a more detailed explanation - http://answers.ros.org/question/187694/depthimage_to_laserscan-choose-which-part-of-the-image-is-scanned/

---

Originally posted by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) with karma: 170 on 2015-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0